# why does join search not use index in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

table schema like this:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE tbl1(seq int, companyid int, field1 int NULL, field2 int NULL,  field3 int NULL,  field4 int NULL, field5 int NULL);
sqlite>   create index tbl1_idx on tbl1(seq);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE tbl2(symbolid int, relatedcompanyid char(64),  value char(64),  field1 int NULL, field2 int NULL,  field3 int NULL,  field4 int NULL, field5 int NULL);
sqlite>  create index tbl2_idx on tbl2(relatedcompanyid);

sqlite> explain query plan select tbl2.value  from tbl2,  tbl1 where tbl1.seq = 100 and tbl1.companyid = tbl2.relatedcompanyid;
0|1|TABLE tbl1 WITH INDEX tbl1_idx
1|0|TABLE tbl2
```

why the second step not use index tbl2_idx, since companyid has got in step one? if use index, this search will be much faster
How to optimize this sql query?

Comment: If you are running sqlite 3.2.3+ maybe try `ANALYZE` first?

Comment: I have tried, how to explain the ANALYZE result?

Answer (score 1):

`tbl1.companyid` and `tbl2.relatedcompanyid` have different [affinities](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) (`int` is NUMBER, `char(64)` is TEXT), so comparing values in these two columns [might require type conversions](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#expraff) in some cases, so this lookup cannot be optimized with an index.

Answer (score 0):

thank you. It's very helpful

```
CREATE TABLE tbl2(symbolid int, relatedcompanyid int,  value char(64),  field1 int NULL, field2 int NULL,  field3 int NULL,  field4 int NULL, field5 int NULL);
create index tbl2_idx on tbl2(relatedcompanyid);
explain query plan select tbl2.value  from tbl2,  tbl1 where tbl1.seq = 100 and tbl1.companyid = tbl2.relatedcompanyid;
0|0|1|SEARCH TABLE tbl1 USING INDEX tbl1_idx (seq=?)
0|1|0|SEARCH TABLE tbl2 USING INDEX tbl2_idx (relatedcompanyid=?)
```